# Where is the HTML source code of a page when using angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a drop down list and was wondering what the 'values' are of that dropdownlist

```
 <div>
    <select ng-model="lastItem" ng-options="cc.congressLongName for cc in ccList"></select>
</div>
```

But since when I view the source code all I see for the page is

```
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

How do I see my source code when using angular   ?

EDIT: The only way to see the output form a angularJS view seems to be to use developer tools; $('body').html(). I tried all the other methods but the true HTML is not shown.

Comment: The values could come from anywhere. You would have to read the JavaScript to find out where.

Comment: developer tools; $('body').html()

Comment: Normally the values are in the raw HTML .. but angular seems to hide this.. so what I am wondering is how can I see this raw HTML that seems to not show up anymore with using angularjs ? Or maybe im missing some basic concepts of using angular  ?

Comment: $('body').html()  from f10 IE tools is showing me the missing info. Why doesn't this show up using 'View HTML' ?

Comment: @punkouter That's because IE is terrible at debugging *dynamic* content, you'll have to hit the '**DOM Refresh**' button in IE to update the Live HTML. [This Button - See Link](http://dropshado.ws/post/46430148565/refresh-button-in-ie-developer-tools)

Comment: where is the 'dom refresh' button  ? I don't see it in IE or IE devtools

Comment: if you are going to use angular, you should really learn to use browser console/developer tools intimately. Can see the live html amonst many other things

Answer (score 3):

In Chrome developers tools you can use the Network view to see the cached pages (should be similar for Firefox). You can then view the output from there.

When you open the Developer tools you should see 'Elements', 'Resources', 'Network', etc. Click Network and you should see the HTML pages that are loaded. You can filter the content by selecting XHR in the bottom bar. The output is displayed nicely in the Response tab.

The following image show the network view (referenced from the Google Developers site)

[image]

If you inspect the view you should also see the values.

Comment: I have Chrome. Where is this option in the Developer tools to show the full HTML that I am missing ?

Comment: @punkouter Press `F12` on your Keybooard.

Comment: I know that. But I mean to show the missing HMTL that does not show up normally in 'html source'

Comment: See my answer to your question (and check out the links for more info)...I know it works in Firefox, but I don't have Chrome installed right now to confirm what you can see in that browser

Answer (score 0):

You can see the generated source code in Firefox by bringing up [Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector) via `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I` (for the whole page) or right clicking and selecting "Inspect Element" to bring focus on a particular element (like your drop down).

Chrome also has [DevTools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts) that allow you to view the source via `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`I`.

Safari has [Web Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) to accomplish this.